# Set Language of NodeJs Errors

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a way to set what language node will output errors in? For example, if I wanted to use node as a Spanish user and my error was "Function not found", can node output "Función no encontrada" instead?

Comment: I don't think Node comes in different languages, so you might have to catch the relevant errors, and return your translated text instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As errors, exceptions, stacktraces, logs etc. are not user centric, it's not recommended to have them in other language than English. It does not affect consumers at all and would limit developer staffing.

That said, you can catch the exception and give any message you desire. For example:

```
try {
  throw new Error("El errore");
} catch (e) {
  e.message = "The horror"
  throw e;
}
```

Comment: That would also mean that dependencies used by Node.js and packages need to get localized as well. It's an unnecessarily complex task.

Comment: @LEQADA As opposed to what?

Comment: @user229044 sorry for not being more clear. What I want to say is that developers are already solving complex tasks and localizing everything to hundreds of different languages and supporting them would make their life El horror.

Comment: @LEQADA Lots of apps are already localized, including their error messages, so I don't really see what you mean. Localization is a real thing that lots of apps do, and it's not that big a deal.

Comment: @user229044 apps have focus groups. They select focus groups based on a potential revenue. Programming languages and frameworks normally are not focusing any group of people. They are generic and for everyone. Localization will not bring a big value for them.

Comment: @LEQADA I'm not sure what that has to do with the answer we're comment on. It doesn't suggest localizing Node or its dependencies or adding localization to any framework.